# migrate to Exchange Online without MAPI

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

We are currently planing to migrate from an hosted exchange provider to Exchange online (O365).
We are planing to do a cutover migration. 
When creating an migration endpoint the connection fails when trying to connect to the MAPI Server. It seems that in contrast to what https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cutover-migration-to-Office-365-9496e93c-1e59-41a8-9bb3-6e8df0cd81b4#ID0EAABAAA=Run_a_cutover_migration states the migration client requires MAPI access.
The Current Provider does not allow MAPI access. Currently only RPC over HTTP is supported.
We might have the option to enable MAPI over HTTP and potentially MRS Proxy.
I can not find the information if the migration process support MAPI over HTTP instead of MAPI.

Can you tell me if
 1. The Microsoft Migration support MAPI/HTTP
 2. The Microsoft Migration support MRS Proxy

Thanks in advance
Clemens

**UPDATE** 22.09.2017:
The following Error is shown when trying to connect to the server. I also used the "Remote connectivity analyzer" to test the connection and get the autodiscover XML. I got the exchange and RPC/HTTP server from that xml.

```
MapiExceptionCallFailed: Unable to make connection to the server. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1249) Diagnostic context: Lid: 49064 dwParam: 0x3 Lid: 59431 EMSMDB.EcDoConnectEx called [length=147] Lid: 34855 EMSMDB.EcDoConnectEx returned [ec=0x4E1][length=56][latency=31] Lid: 59505 StoreEc: 0x4E1 Lid: 50544 ClientVersion: 15.20.56.10 Lid: 51056 ServerVersion: 14.3.351.4000 Lid: 52080 StoreEc: 0x4E1 Lid: 51152 Lid: 52465 StoreEc: 0x4E1 Lid: 60065 Lid: 33777 StoreEc: 0x4E1 Lid: 59805 Lid: 52487 StoreEc: 0x4E1 Lid: 19778 Lid: 27970 StoreEc: 0x4E1 Lid: 17730 Lid: 25922 StoreEc: 0x4E1
```

Comment: I'm certain that a cutover migration doesn't require MAPI access. What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: @joeqwerty he may be running into this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/2903050/-we-weren-t-able-to-connect-to-the-remote-server-error-when-you-try-to  -- with it being a "hosted Exchange provider" the issue can still apply.  Also, with migrating from hosted Exchange you may need to work with that provider to make this happen.

Comment: I tried to do manual setup and failed. I updated the OP with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Just some other possible options here, if you do not find a way to do that via MAPI over HTTP.

**Option 1 (via [IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-you-need-to-know-about-migrating-your-IMAP-mailboxes-to-Office-365-3fe19996-29bc-4879-aab9-5a622b2f1481)):**

1. Enable IMAP on Exchange Online (aka Office 365)
2. Using IMAP and then performing an [IMAP sync task](https://imapsync.lamiral.info/)

However this will not take over the agenda or contacts. That would be an per user approach using the Outlook client (Import & Export).

**Option 2 (via two mailboxes and Outlook):**

1. Create the mailboxes on Exchange Online
2. Cut over the MX record from your domain
3. on your old environment put forwarder in place to user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com (or something like that)
4. Map both mailboxes on the users and inform them to use only the new one whenever possible. Over the time emails will be only in the new mailbox. You can also move elements from one mailbox to another via the Outlook client then. Or you can let the users perform that.

**Option 3 (via local PST file):**

1. Create the mailboxes on Exchange Online
2. Cut over the MX record from your domain
3. Let your users move there stuff into a PST file, and then let them re-import

Note here: This approach often destory the "last changed" timestamp, so an archiving isn´t working as expected for these elements as there is now a new timestamp. This often is confusing a backup software. We saw that this will also destoy re-occouring meetings and a re-schedule is no longer working as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for these options. We already considered these. Option 1 is not possible because our Users highly depend on calendars and contacts. Option 2 is the last resort option but we try to prevent this (actually we currently plan that each user exports a PST file and re-imports it after adding the new account as last resort).

Comment: That would be the worst option... if you users higly depend on the calendar then this approach will kill all kind of "rescedule" features.